# Useful stack traces for futures/parallel code

Tags: scala, zio

When running code in threads the stack traces oftentimes do not show the logic flow of the code where it was assembled/defined, 
but the execution stack trace. This is oftentimes not the information I need for debugging and context.

ZIO does a great job of giving context on what went wrong and where.

However if you have a legacy project that's unlikely to be ported to zio, how can I get similar exception/context info without having to rewrite all my futures and monads?

Answer (score 2):

The ZIO stack traces are indeed amazing. We have added a very poor relative to this with a method called `withDiagnostic`. This records the file and line number where the method is called, and returns a new future that maps the any exceptions the future returns to include the details.

It uses the [scalactic `Position` typeclass](http://doc.scalactic.org/3.0.1-2.12/org/scalactic/source/Position.html) to get the source position.

```
object FutureUtils {

  implicit class RichFuture[A](future: Future[A]) {
    def withDiagnostic(implicit pos: Position, ec: ExecutionContext): Future[A] = {
      FutureUtils.withDiagnostic(future)
    }
  }


  def withDiagnostic[A](future: Future[A])(implicit pos: Position, ec: ExecutionContext): Future[A] = {
    future.recoverWith {
      case t: Throwable =>
        val diagnosticInfo = s"(${pos.fileName}:${pos.lineNumber})"
        if (t.getMessage.endsWith(diagnosticInfo)) Future.failed(t)
        else Future.failed(new Exception(t.getMessage + " " + diagnosticInfo, t))
    }
  }
}
```

Here is a short example of using this in the Ammonite repl. Note in the last example the file and line number from  the for comprehension are included in the error message `java.lang.Exception: Where did I fail? (cmd10.sc:3)` In this case `cmd10.sc:3` is the file ammonite generates to parse this line.

```
Welcome to the Ammonite Repl 1.7.1
(Scala 2.12.10 Java 1.8.0_131)
If you like Ammonite, please support our development at www.patreon.com/lihaoyi
@ import org.scalactic.source._
import org.scalactic.source._

@ import scala.concurrent._
import scala.concurrent._

@ import scala.concurrent.duration._
import scala.concurrent.duration._

@ object FutureUtils {

      implicit class RichFuture[A](future: Future[A]) {
        def withDiagnostic(implicit pos: Position, ec: ExecutionContext): Future[A] = {
          FutureUtils.withDiagnostic(future)
        }
      }


      def withDiagnostic[A](future: Future[A])(implicit pos: Position, ec: ExecutionContext): Future[A] = {
        future.recoverWith {
          case t: Throwable =>
            val diagnosticInfo = s"(${pos.fileName}:${pos.lineNumber})"
            if (t.getMessage.endsWith(diagnosticInfo)) Future.failed(t)
            else Future.failed(new Exception(t.getMessage + " " + diagnosticInfo, t))
        }
      }
    }
defined object FutureUtils

@ import FutureUtils._
import FutureUtils._

@ implicit val ec: scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext = scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.global
ec: ExecutionContext = scala.concurrent.impl.ExecutionContextImpl@434514d8

@ def futureSuccessful(i: Int): Future[Int] = Future.successful(i)
defined function futureSuccessful

@ def futureFailed: Future[Int] = Future.failed(new Exception("Where did I fail?"))
defined function futureFailed

@ val f1 = for {
      i <- futureSuccessful(3)
      j <- futureFailed
    } yield i + j
f1: Future[Int] = Future(<not completed>)

@ Await.result(f1, 1.second)
java.lang.Exception: Where did I fail?
  ammonite.$sess.cmd7$.futureFailed(cmd7.sc:1)
  ammonite.$sess.cmd8$.$anonfun$f1$1(cmd8.sc:3)
  ammonite.$sess.cmd8$.$anonfun$f1$1$adapted(cmd8.sc:2)
  scala.concurrent.Future.$anonfun$flatMap$1(Future.scala:307)
  scala.concurrent.impl.Promise.$anonfun$transformWith$1(Promise.scala:41)
  scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:64)
  java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$RunnableExecuteAction.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1402)
  java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
  java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
  java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
  java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)


@ val f2 = for {
      i <- futureSuccessful(3).withDiagnostic
      j <- futureFailed.withDiagnostic
    } yield i + j
f2: Future[Int] = Future(<not completed>)

@ Await.result(f2, 1.second)
java.lang.Exception: Where did I fail? (cmd10.sc:3)
  ammonite.$sess.cmd3$FutureUtils$$anonfun$withDiagnostic$1.applyOrElse(cmd3.sc:15)
  ammonite.$sess.cmd3$FutureUtils$$anonfun$withDiagnostic$1.applyOrElse(cmd3.sc:11)
  scala.concurrent.Future.$anonfun$recoverWith$1(Future.scala:417)
  scala.concurrent.impl.Promise.$anonfun$transformWith$1(Promise.scala:41)
  scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:64)
  java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$RunnableExecuteAction.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1402)
  java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
  java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
  java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
  java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)
java.lang.Exception: Where did I fail?
  ammonite.$sess.cmd7$.futureFailed(cmd7.sc:1)
  ammonite.$sess.cmd10$.$anonfun$f2$1(cmd10.sc:3)
  ammonite.$sess.cmd10$.$anonfun$f2$1$adapted(cmd10.sc:2)
  scala.concurrent.Future.$anonfun$flatMap$1(Future.scala:307)
  scala.concurrent.impl.Promise.$anonfun$transformWith$1(Promise.scala:41)
  scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:64)
  java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$RunnableExecuteAction.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1402)
  java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
  java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
  java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
  java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)
```

We rely on this a lot for testing akka actors with the ask pattern akka typed. Here is an example of a test method returning response to an ask (notice that it included an `implicit pos` parameter, now the file and line that calls `askEnqueueJob` will appear in the message.

```
def askEnqueueJob(referenceId: ReferenceId, tenant: Tenant)(implicit pos: Position): Future[EnqueueJobResponse] = {
  val job = newEnqueuedJob(referenceId = referenceId, tenant = tenant)

  withDiagnostic {
    tenantActor ? (sender => ProcessJobRequest(EnqueueJob(job, sender)))
  }
}
```